# How do I find a particular node in a JavaFX node tree?

Tags: java, user-interface, tabs, javafx-8, nodes

I have created a "mainPane" tab pane in SceneBuilder 8 with 3 tabs: Home, Configuration and Reports. In a separate FXML file, I have created a second tab pane "userPane."

At runtime, I want to put my userPane in the "Configuration" tab of the mainPane. To do that, I have to get a reference to the Configuration tab.

I can do this by manually traversing the mainPane's node tree looking for a TabPane with the "Configuration" title. Although this will work, it's ugly and I'd rather gnaw my own leg off.

Is there an easy way to locate a particular node within the mainPane's node tree?

Comment: Wouldn't you just do this in the controller for the `mainPane`? It will already have a reference to the "Configuration" tab (or can easily get one); and it would seem to be the natural place to load the FXML file containing the `userPane`. Probably you need to add some code that illustrates the structure you have.

Comment: @James_D There, again, to get a reference to the configuration pane, I'd still need to manually traverse the tree, although I'd be starting one level further down.

Comment: Why would you need to do that? Isn't the tab defined in the FXML file? You need to post some code to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @James_D The tab is defined in the FXML file, but I'm adding the userPane in code at runtime. `FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(resource));` provides a pointer to the root node of the loaded resource, but that's an AnchorPane. I'd have to use AnchorPane.getChildren() to get the TabPane, then TabPane.getTabs() to get the tab list, which I'd have to loop through to find the one labelled "Config". From there, I could get a reference to its content pane by using Tab.getContent(), or I could just replace the existing contents with Tab.setContent().

Comment: Why don't you just inject the tab into the controller using `@FXML`? [That's how it is normally done.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#fxml_annotation) Maybe I am missing something, but it seems like you are going out of your way to avoid the usual way of doing things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at the "lookup" method of the class Node. It does what you are looking for.

Comment: I looked at the lookup method, and it seemed ideal. However, it requires a CSS Selector as a parameter, and I was unsure whether this was the id, fx:id, or a selector as used in a CSS referenced by the FXML, Since the userPane doesn't reference a CSS, there is no such selector available to me. Is the required parameter the id or the fx:id?

Comment: I really consider lookups as a bit of a hack, especially if you are trying to reference nodes you have created yourself (somewhere in your code). Lookups can be useful to get nodes internal to library-defined controls when there is no API to give you the access you need, but these are edge cases. If you have defined the node yourself, you have a (more robust) mechanism to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the [usual mechanism of `@FXML`-injection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#fxml_annotation):

Main Pane FXML file:

```xml
<AnchorPane ...fx:controller="com.mycompany.myproject.MainController">

    <TabPane>

        <tabs>

            <!-- ... -->

            <Tab text="Configuration" fx:id="configTab"/>

        </tabs>

    </TabPane>

</AnchorPane>
```

and then

```
public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private Tab configTab ;

    // ...

}
```

Now if you get to load the fxml for the user pane in the main controller, you just do

```
configTab.setContent(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("path/to/userPane.fxml")));
```

If not, you can just define a method, e.g `setConfigContent(Parent content)` in the main controller and invoke it from wherever you do load the user pane.